# Xcode 4.6 running OS 10.7.5

Tags: iphone, xcode

The App Store says I have an update available: XCode 4.6. I'm still running OS X 10.7.5. Will XCode 4.6 run on this OS? I looked at the App Store and Mac Developer site and couldn't find what OS version was required for 4.6.Kindly give me link for Xcode 4.6 running OS 10.7.5. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It will work without any issue. Maybe this page about [Xcode Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html) will be useful for you

Answer (score 1):

When the Mac App Store shows the Application it should run on your system because as on iOS you can decide as developer which OS versions you support. Apple decided to show you the update - so they decided to allow 10.7.5. There are also no information about discontinuing support for 10.7.5 in Xcode 4.6 [release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW216).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'm running 4.6 on 10.7.5 here.
You can go right ahead and download it from the app store.

If you're concerned about it screwing up your existing work, you could rename your existing install. (to ".old" or something)